# Como cambio el fondo de un JList al pasar el mouse por arriba y al cliquear

Tags: java

El problema es que quería añadirle un `JSeparator` a mi `JList` y entonces vi [esta](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swingexamples/add_separator_listbox.htm) pagina en Google y lo implemente, no se todavía nada de `CellRenderer` y no me ayudo mucho esa pagina, porque al implementarlo me aparece un espacio entre el `JSeparator` y el ítem, que no debería aparecer en la imagen de la pagina:

[image: Imagen de como aparece en el juego]

Entonces, quisiera corregir eso y a la vez que al pasar el mouse por encima de cada item se ponga el fondo de otro color.

**Asi tengo invocado mi JList:**

```
//JList que se vuelve visible al presionar Game  
Object[] items = { "      Nuevo                    (F2)", new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), "      Novato", "      Intermedio", "      Experto", 
                       "      Personalizar...", "      Best Times...", "      Exit"};      
ListaJuego = new JList<>(items);        
ListaJuego.setLayout(null);
ListaJuego.setBounds(0, 18, 145, 178);
ListaJuego.setBackground(new Color(200, 255, 200));
ListaJuego.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, new Color(20, 100, 20)));
ListaJuego.setFont(new Font("Bahnschrift", 0, 13));
Separador Separador = new Separador();
ListaJuego.setCellRenderer(Separador);
ListaJuego.setFixedCellHeight(25);
ListaJuego.setVisible(false);
add(ListaJuego);
```

**Asi tengo invocado mi la clase Separador**

```
class Separador extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Object> list,
      Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
         if(value instanceof JSeparator){
            return (Component)value;
         }else{
            setText(value.toString());
         }
         return this;
   }   
}
```

Sinceramente quiero algo igual a esto pero con colores diferentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Porque no usas un JMenu y JMenuItem? Se le puede agregar un JSeparator con un add y sin implementar renderizadores para hacer lo mismo que estas haciendo (al menos en la imagen).

Comment: @JFrame Hola, pues no lo añadí porque pensé que seria mas fácil el tema de ponerle color al fondo, modificar los textos, y el ponerle el `JSeparator` ya que yo quiero ponerlo de manera que no ocupe todo el largo del `Jlist` si no que empieze desde el inicio del texto